# Call shell command within PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I wonder how to run shell command within PhantomJS, return back result of execution and assign it to variable.

e.g. there is a phantomjs script:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn
var execFile = require("child_process").execFile

var child = spawn("/usr/bin/php", ["script.php"])

child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
})
```

and simple php script:

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

This example just prints to console "test", but how to use this returned data? Is it possible to assign it to variable and use it in next PhantomJS steps?

Comment: Just use `data` to do what you want? You're already working with the returned data. Instead of logging it to the console, just use it to do what you want.

Comment: yes, but how to use data outside child.stdout.on function?

Comment: You can't. The function is asynchronous. The most you can do is pass `data` to another function, and then define that function in the main body.

Comment: Why are you using PhantomJS for this? PhantomJS is for UI/browser testing. Browsers normally don't let you run shell scripts. You can use Node.js if you want to execute javascript in a server environment.

Answer (score 1):

In here http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/ and try "process.execFile" method.
I am succeed with this.

e.g. there is a phantomjs script:

```
var execFile = require("child_process").execFile;
execFile("php", ["a.php", 'bbb'], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", stdout);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

and simple php script:

```
<?php print_r($argv); ?>
```

output:

```
execFileSTDOUT: Array
(
    [0] => a.php
    [1] => bbb
)
```